# Modularize installation of python packages - how to stack environments

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, environment-modules

Let's say I have two locations `/A` and `/B` in which I installed python packages using pip's "user sheme" `PYTHONUSERBASE=/some/folder pip install --user SomePackage`. When installing Files in `/B`, is there a way to make pip aware of the packages installed in `/A` and avoid a double installation of packages?

Background: Our software stack is modularized using [environment-modules](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Modules are composable in the sense that each module should be its own, immutable entity but can depend on other modules.

- We have a **python-base** package which installs e.g. `pandas` and `numpy` using `PYTHONUSERBASE`.
- A **python-bindings** package depending on **python-base** and **my-cpp-app** should be introduced

I would like pip to pick up the packages in **python-base** and not reinstall them in **python-bindings** for two reasons

- Save space (not important)
- Ensure that versions of requirements are consistent and therefore compatible between each other (very important)